# How to add item to listview at runtime

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to know how to add a new text view to appearing `ListView` in android, ( for example. when I  click on some button a new list item is added to the list view )?

Comment: It depends on how you are populating your ListView currently. What kind of adapter does your ListView have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply add the object to the container that contains the objects displayed by the listview. Then you tell the listView adapter that a change has occured:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
list.add(someObject);
((ArrayAdapter<Object>) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: why is `setContentView(R.layout.list_view);` needed? isn't `notifyDataSetChanged` enough?

Comment: isn't `notifyDataSetChanged` async? so `setContentView` might be called too early, no?

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged is enough. I have used it. When I used `setContentView(R.layout.list_view);` my screen turned white. On removing  setContentView(R.layout.list_view); it worked like a charm!!!