# how to refresh listView(with adapter) after callbacks in android

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have an `Activity` with a `ListView` attached to a `custom adapter`.

I have a callback which indicates an drawable item finished downloading.

It's invoked many times (acter each resource is downloaded).

In my callback I switch to ui-thread and I set a new array to the same adapter.

Then I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

But the activity list isn't refreshed to the new icons.

what else do I need to do?

1) call `mListView.requestLayout()` ? but how can I know when?

as `notifyDataSetChanged` is async and I cann't know when is it done.

2) override `adapter's destroyView`? so I will not create a new listItem, but use the existing one?

my Adapter's code:

public class SettingValueAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private SettingsValue[] values;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public SettingValueAdapter(Context context) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public SettingsValue[] getValues() {
    return values;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (values == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return values.length;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return values==null? null : values[arg0];       
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_item, null);
    }
    SettingsValue item = values[position];
    CheckedTextView name = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
    ImageView iconView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon);
    if (iconView != null && (item != null) && (item.icon != null)) {
        iconView.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        iconView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        iconView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    name.setText(item.display);
    name.setChecked(item.isSelected);
    View container = convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemContainer);
    if (position == 0) {
        if (position == values.length-1) {
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_selector_single);
        } else {
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_selector_top);
        }
    } else {
        if (position == values.length-1) {
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_selector_bottom);
        } else {
            container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_selector_middle);
        }
    }
    container.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return convertView;
}

public void setValues(SettingsValue[] values) {
    this.values = values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

MyActivity's code:

```
public class CategoriesActivity extends ActivityBase {
    private Category[] categories;

    SettingValueAdapter adapter;
    ListView            mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_values);
        ((TitleBar) findViewById(R.id.theTitleBar)).init(this,
                DisplayStrings.DS_CATEGORIES);

        adapter = new SettingValueAdapter(this);

        DriveToNativeManager nativeManager = DriveToNativeManager.getInstance();
        nativeManager.getCategories(new CategoriesListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Category[] aCategories) {
                categories = aCategories;

                NativeManager nativeManager = AppService.getNativeManager();
                SettingsValue[] values = new SettingsValue[categories.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                    values[i] = new SettingsValue(
                            categories[i].value,
                            nativeManager
                                    .getLanguageString(categories[i].displayString),
                            false);
                    values[i].icon = ResManager
                            .GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
                }
                adapter.setValues(values);
            }
        });
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settingsValueList);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CategoriesActivity.this,
                        SearchActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PublicMacros.SEARCH_CATEGORY,
                        categories[position].value);
                intent.putExtra(PublicMacros.SEARCH_MODE,
                        PublicMacros.FREE_SEARCH);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void refreshListIcons() {

//      if (categories != null) {
//          NativeManager nativeManager = AppService.getNativeManager();
//          SettingsValue[] values = new SettingsValue[categories.length];
//          for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
//              values[i] = new SettingsValue(
//                      categories[i].value,
//                      nativeManager
//                              .getLanguageString(categories[i].displayString),
//                      false);
//              values[i].icon = ResManager
//                      .GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
//          }
//          

            if (categories != null) {

                SettingsValue[] values = adapter.getValues();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    values[i].icon = ResManager
                            .GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
                }


            adapter.setValues(values);
        }

    }
}
```

I call `refreshIconsList` from the callback.

but, as I have said - the list isn't refreshed on runtime, but only after existing and re-entering the acitivty.

I have tried this, but no help:

```
    public void refreshListIcons() {

//      if (categories != null) {
//          NativeManager nativeManager = AppService.getNativeManager();
//          SettingsValue[] values = new SettingsValue[categories.length];
//          for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
//              values[i] = new SettingsValue(
//                      categories[i].value,
//                      nativeManager
//                              .getLanguageString(categories[i].displayString),
//                      false);
//              values[i].icon = ResManager
//                      .GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
//          }
//          
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (categories != null) {

                SettingsValue[] values = adapter.getValues();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    values[i].icon = ResManager
                            .GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
                }

                adapter.setValues(values);

                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` should be enough. Could you show the adapter code, is there a reason you need to set a new array can't you just update the current one?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325437/how-to-add-item-to-listview-at-runtime, there he added `setContentView` in addition to `notifyAll`. why?

Comment: is the `refreshIconList` called from a asynctask or some other async process? if so you may need to run the adapter.setValues on UI thread `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { adapter.setValues(values); } } );`

Comment: another async process asks the ui-thread to run `refreshIconList`. anyway I have tried `runOnUiThread` and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually using `notifyDataSetChanged()` will work. Since your values are just an array, is there a particular reason why you're using extending `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter` (which provides `add` `remove` and `clear` functions for the underlying array). I suspect that using `BaseAdapter` isn't notifying in the way you may be intending. If that doesn't end up working for you, try force refreshing the child views using `invalidate()` on the `View` after setting the new values.

As an aside, I would highly advise you use the "view holder pattern" if you plan to contain many rows in this list for speed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- mListView.setAdapter(adapter); on your onCreate() in the activity.
- public void refreshListIcons() {

  ```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  {

  @Override
  public void run() {
      if (categories != null) {

          SettingsValue[] values = adapter.getValues();
          for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
              values[i].icon = ResManager
                      .GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
          }


          adapter.addAll(values); // *** ADD THIS LINE***
      }
  }
  });
  ```

  }

The problem is when you setAdapter after a callback. 
So you have to init the adapter before the call and add the values after the callback